# I'm trying to delete an item from listView,get its elements from a cursor,and when i click the button it's deleting the last element in the cursor

Tags: android-studio, listview, android-cursoradapter

this code doesn't delete the element which I pressed its button ,but it deletes the last element in the cursor.

here's my button with the Listener

```
ImageButton imageButton =convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_cancel);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM ordersTable WHERE _id = ? ;", new String[]{String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")))});
                    cursor.requery();
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try to follow the best practice of stackoverflow, while asking the question

Comment: i don't want code changements , i just wants to know how to do that
i want to delete a specific item in a listView with CursorAdapter , how can i do that , please ?